# Set custom event items dynamically for each log call using Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, logging

We're using the Zend_Log class to update a few different "watchdog" database tables (that log different events: Batch scripts running, new data being processed, files generated, etc.).

Here is my current code (before the issue I'm looking into fixing.)

```
$writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Db($db, 'watchdog', array(
    'priority'  => 'priority',
    'message'   => 'message',
    'owner'     => 'owner',
));

$logger = new Zend_Log($writer);
$logger->setEventItem('owner', 'MODULE_NAME');
```

This works perfectly fine. But, I want to add a database column called datetime that is a call to `time()` at the time of the event. So, in theory, it would be something like this:

```
$writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Db($db, 'watchdog', array(
    'priority'  => 'priority',
    'message'   => 'message',
    'owner'     => 'owner',
    'datetime'  => 'datetime',
));

$logger = new Zend_Log($writer);
$logger->setEventItem('owner', 'MODULE_NAME');
$logger->setEventItem('datetime', time());
```

The problem I'm running into is that, obviously, the call to time() runs at the first time `Zend_Log::setEventItem` is called and not when `Zend_Log::info()` is called. So, the question is, how do I get the `time()` to be called and stored in my DB when `Zend_Log::info()` is called? Will I need to extend `Zend_Log_Writer_Db` with a more custom class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution I wanted to put out there is to use `Zend_Db_Expr` with a MySQL function like NOW() or TIMESTAMP().

```
$dblog->setEventItem('datetime', new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()'));
```

Comment: This is ultimately exactly what I was looking for. Both extending and using an expression are good answers, but expressions makes it a bit smoother.

Answer (score 1):

Extending seems the best idea.

I would create a timestampable event, with default columns `created_at` and `updated_at`, and change it automatically on each log write.

(this is a [Timestampable behaviour from Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/pl/behaviors:core-behaviors:timestampable))

```
My_Log_Writer_Db_Timebstampable extends Zend_Log_Writer_Db
```